# Using Angular-Material 5 with Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I'm working on a new project which is using Angular v6. I need to integrate some UI components which is built on top of Angular material v5 into the project. Do I need to downgrade the Angular to v5 in the project to use these UI Components ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular material v5 is compatible with Angular v6. You do not need to downgrade your Angular version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a place where I can check for the mapping with different versions ?

Comment: @nbsamurai I could not find one.